# wagtail WagtailFormBlock localization

Tags: python, django, internationalization, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a `WagtailFormBlock` `StreamField` in my project. When I tried to translate my pages with that `StreamField`, I can only translate block's `form_action` and `form_reference` but can't change form as it is.

Is it any way to change form when translate some page?

[image: img reference]

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @sabrina , not at all